# How to convert 2022-08-16T06:25:00.000 to HH:mm

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to convert date from API `"2022-08-16T06:25:00.000"` to HH:mm (6:25) but getting `DateTimeParseException`.
My code: `ZonedDateTime.parse(it.time[0], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"))`

```json
"time": [
    "2022-08-16T06:25:00.000",
    "2022-08-16T07:40:00.000"
],
```

Comment: That pattern is used to convert that `String` to a `ZonedDateTime`. The pattern has to match that input. `"HH:mm"` does not match `"2022-08-16T06:25:00.000"`.

Comment: Which zone are you trying to parse? I can't see one… Oh, and the `DateTimeFormatter` applied in a `parse` method should match the pattern of the `String` to be parsed, not the desired output! You will need define another `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: `parse()` is meant to read a string and convert it to a more fancy format, in your case `ZonedDateTime`. The pattern is to tell the parser how to interpret the input string.

Comment: instead of  `ZonedDateTime`, I would try `LocalDateTime` since it does not require a time zone - it should also be able to parse the given format without needing a `DateTimeFormatter` (format is ISO-8601, which is the default one) - see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) || then you can format it using a `DateTimeFormatter` created with `"HH:mm"` or even `"H:mm"` (for `6:25`)

Comment: You are using the standard ISO format with that ugly `T`. A `LocalDateTime` will by default use that format for parsing. A `ZonedDateTime` would still need a time zone.

Comment: 6:25 is not  formatted as HH:mm, it does not have a leading zero…

Answer (score 2):

```
String dateTimeStr = "2022-08-16T06:25:00.000";
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
String time = dateTime.format(fmt);
System.out.println(time);
```

or, if you want to use the time as an instance of LocalTime, you can get it by `dateTime.toLocalTime()`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define any `DateTimeFormatter` in this situation.

1. use a `LocalDateTime` because the input `String` does not hold any information about the zone
2. don't use a `DateTimeFormatter` for parsing that only parses hour of day and minutes of hour, the `String` to be parsed just contains more information

Here's an example without any `DateTimeFormatter` explicitly defined (but it will use default ones for parsing, at least):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input
    String fromApi = "2022-08-16T06:25:00.000";
    // parse it to a LocalDateTime because there's no zone in the String
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(fromApi);
    // extract the time-of-day part
    LocalTime localTime = localDateTime.toLocalTime();
    // and print its toString() implicitly
    System.out.println(localTime);
}
```

Output: `06:25`

The above code will produce output of the pattern `HH:mm`, which will have leading zeros at hours of day to always have a two-digit representation.

If you insist on single-digit hours of day, you will have to prepare a `DateTimeFormatter`, like in this alternative example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input
    String fromApi = "2022-08-16T06:25:00.000";
    // parse it to a LocalDateTime because there's no zone in the String
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(fromApi);
    // extract the time-of-day part
    LocalTime localTime = localDateTime.toLocalTime();
    // prepare a DateTimeFormatter that formats single-digit hours of day
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm");
    // print the LocalTime formatted by that DateTimeFormatter
    System.out.println(localTime.format(dtf));
}
```

Output this time: `6:25`

Answer (score 1):

The other answers use Java. Since you've added a [kotlin] tag, here is a Kotlin-based answer for the sake of completeness. In order to make it different to the Java answers, I'm using kotlinx.datetime, which is still at the experimental stage at version 0.4.0.

```
import kotlinx.datetime.LocalDateTime

fun main() {
    println(LocalDateTime.parse("2022-08-16T06:25:00.000").time)  // prints "06:25"

    // If you want "6:25" you can format it yourself:
    println(with(LocalDateTime.parse("2022-08-16T06:25:00.000")) {
        "$hour:$minute"
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about different approach

```
String dateTimeStr = "2022-08-16T06:25:00.000";
Matcher m=Pattern.of("T(\\d{2}:\\d{2}):").matcher(dateTimeStr);
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group(1);; //should print 06:25
```

Comment: This is very ugly. You should feel ashamed of this code :)

Answer (score -1):

And yet another "alternative" answer. It relies on the fact that in an ISO-compliant date-time format, the time starts in the 11th position.

```
private static final int ISO_TIME_POS = 11;
....
String dateTimeStr = "2022-08-16T06:25:00.000";
String timeStr = dateTimeStr.substring(ISO_TIME_POS, ISO_TIME_POS + 5);
System.out.println(timeStr);  // prints "06:25"
```

Comment: I believe that you meant your answer as a kind of a joke, but don't forget that you have responsibility for the Stack Overflow Programmers, and do not place here anything which may be copy and pasted into production code by them :)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming: "The term cargo cult programmer may apply when anyone inexperienced with the problem at hand copies some program code from one place to another with little understanding of how it works or whether it is required."

Comment: @HonzaZidek it's in the same league as [Antonios's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73205629/13963086) but _much_ more performant. Both of these answers rely on the fact that we know the input format to be an ISO time format. Antonios's answer searches for the 'T', but my answer shows that we already know exactly where that T is. It cannot be ISO-compliant and be in any other place than the 11th position. Thanks anyway - your comment has given me an idea to edit my answer to make it more comprehensible.

Comment: Your are right, I downvoted equally both your answers :)